# Bitrix, изменение разделов товара sql запросом

Tags: sql, битрикс

В битриксе необходимо массово удалить товары из определенного раздела. С помощью sql запроса:

```
delete from b_iblock_section_element where 
IBLOCK_SECTION_ID=413 and IBLOCK_ELEMENT_ID in ("5643","5644","5645","5646")
```

удаляю товары из раздела. Если заходить в эти товары в админке, то видно, что товары удалены из этого раздела, но в паблике они по прежнему отображаются в этом разделе. Если же в админке зайти в эти товары и нажать сохранить, то и в паблике они удаляются из раздела. Пробовал обновить поле timestamp_x в таблице b_iblock_element, но это тоже не сработало.

```
update b_iblock_element set TIMESTAMP_X="2017-08-30 19:00:00" where id 
in ("5643","5644","5645","5646")
```

Можно ли с помощью sql сделать аналог нажатия на кнопку сохранить в товаре?

Answer (score 2):

Это очень дурная практика.  Для любой CMS. Прямая работа с БД это плохо. Битрикс кеширует очень многое, чтобы обеспечить быстродействие. Когда вы выполняете такой запрос система ни чего об этом не знает и не сбрасывает кеш. Кроме того, вы нарушаете логику, потом кто-то решит на вашем проекте подвязаться на событие изменения разделов у товара и оно будет работать не правильно. Кроме того,не зная структуры вы можете нарушить связанность данных.

1. В вашем случае сбросьте в админке весь кеш на странице Автокеширование.
2. Старайтесь так не делать, а использовать функционал АПИ

Comment: На странице Автокеширование, на закладке "Очистка файлов кеша" - выбрал Все и нажал Начать. Ничего не изменилось, в паблике товары по прежнему отображаются

Comment: в таблице b_iblock_element есть поле IBLOCK_SECTION_ID это основной раздел. Возможно у этих товаров 413 был основным